# Алгоритм быстрого поиска

Tags: search

Подскажите оптимальный алгоритм для хранения данных вида: `int user_id; connection *user_con;` с быстрым поиском, вставкой и удалением. user_id не всегда уникальный и может повторяться.

Полагаю, лучший алгоритм: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Двоичное_дерево_поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) но меня смущает то, что там ключ уникален.

Подскажите наилучший алгоритм. Хотелось бы не сильно сложный, мне его еще понимать и реализовывать. )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [хэш таблицу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) размером с ожидаемое количество одновременно используемых уникальных user_id. Каждая ячейка таблицы пусть будет головой двунаправленного списка ваших объектов.